# why the formatting rect I get from WM_GETRECT is (2,2,98,34)?

Tags: windows, api, gdi

```
hWndEdit = CreateWindow(TEXT("edit"),
            NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | ES_LEFT | ES_MULTILINE | ES_AUTOVSCROLL | WS_BORDER,
            pt.x, pt.y, 100, 50, hWnd, (HMENU)ID_EDIT, hInst, NULL);

RECT* rect_temp;

rect_temp = new RECT();

SendMessage(hWndEdit, EM_GETRECT, 0, (LPARAM)rect_temp);
```

PS：the problem is what I get is always (2,2,34,98).

Comment: This is entirely normal.  It uses 2 pixels of padding to keep the text off the border.  The height is determined by the font.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from MSDN for `EM_GETRECT`:

> Gets the formatting rectangle of an edit control. The formatting
>   rectangle is the limiting rectangle into which the control draws the
>   text. The limiting rectangle is independent of the size of the
>   edit-control window. You can send this message to either an edit
>   control or a rich edit control.

the part:

> The limiting rectangle is independent of the size of the edit-control
>   window.

`CreateWindow` creates whole control not what inside it, to modify inside formatting of EDIT use EM_SETRECT .